# wso2-Api RestFull API call using client_id and client_secret

Tags: wso2

I am new to wso2 API, I have created API using API publisher,I am generated API client_id and client_secrete,It works fine fine wso2 API rest client,my question is How to call rest service using restful client? (To use wso2 `client_id` and `client_secret`)

Answer (score 0):

Generally we don't use client_id and client_secret for calling REST APIs. Those are used to generate an OAuth token to invoke REST APIs. What you have to do is get the generated OAuth token in API Store and invoke the API. For that you need to set "Authorization" header in your HTTP request as below.

"Authorization" : "Bearer **Generated_OAuth_Token**"

This is just a basic OAuth scenario. I strongly recommend you to research more on OAuth protocol.